# Cannot connect to Remote Desktop from difference subnet

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a problem about Remote Desktop on Hyper-V Server 2012 R2. I cannot connect to Remote Desktop from a different subnet. The server is multihomed with two NICs, one connects to the public network and another connect to the corporate network. The server also is joined to a domain through the corporate network.

I can Remote Desktop from the public network and corporate network within the same subnet. But when I try to Remote Desktop from the different corporate site (and the different subnet), it is unable to connect. I can connect to any services that run on any VM in that server through corporate network from any site.

This is network diagram:

[image: Corporate Network]

Sorry about the ugly picture. The `Demand-dial VPN` is configure to route all traffic that destination to 10.0.0.0/24 to `Site 2` and route all 10.0.1.0/24 to `Site 1`. The right most is the server I talk about. I can Remote Desktop to `VM 1 (Host)` from any machine within `Site 2` and from internet through `Hyper-V External Switch 1`. But I cannot Remote Desktop to `VM 1 (Host)` from `Site 1` through `Demand-dial VPN`.

Comment: Can you add details about your network and servers including IPs, subnets, network layout, etc.?

Comment: Looks like routing or firewall issue, try trace route

Comment: @TheCleaner I have added more details in the question. If you need other information, please tell me.

Comment: @will.c I tried `tracert` and it request timed out in the last hop. All router response requests except the destination machine. This mean the firewall problem in the target machine?

Comment: quite likely, check your windows firewall remote desktop service. depend on network classification, you may need to enable  the `public` one. Or you can verify by create a test rule to allow 3389 in.

Comment: @will.c Solved. The problems is routing table on destination machine. It route all packets from `Site 1` to gateway of `Hyper-V External Switch 1` instead `Hyper-V External Switch 2`.